# How to resolve "Android media player stopping automatically after some time on streaming"?

Tags: android, media-player, shoutcast

I am using Android media player for streaming shoutcast streaming. Working fine for some time but in some time the media player is stopping automatically after one or two minutes.

I am getting the following in logCat

V/MediaPlayer(12795): message received msg=2, ext1=0, ext2=0

V/MediaPlayer(12795): playback complete

V/MediaPlayer(12795): callback application

V/MediaPlayer(12795): back from callback